# How to redirect page in javascript which has a timer?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my javascript code and it works fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var clock;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(10,{
            countdown: true,
            clockFace: 'MinuteCounter'
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to redirect to another page after the countdown

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: And the documentation for the FlipClock plugin is ... where?  Someone has to read the documenation and see if there is a `done`, `finish` or some other method called at the end.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I think [this](http://flipclockjs.com) is it.

Comment: Can I not use function redirect() and window location="url"

Comment: @royhowie I could have found it ;) I was making subtle, perhaps too subtle, hint to the OP that when someone is using a library or package that they should both name the package and provide a link to its docs.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the [documentation](http://flipclockjs.com#stop) and it appears you just need to add a `stop` property to the object you pass during construction:

```
var clock = $(".clock").FlipClock(10, {
    countdown: true,
    clockFace: "MinuteCounter",
    stop: function () {
        // do whatever you want here, e.g.:
        // window.location.href = "/new/page"
    }
});
```

Since you have set `countdown` to `true`, the clock will eventually hit `0:00`, which will then cause `stop` to fire (a callback function).